# Is it possible to land a 737 on an aircraft carrier?

Tags: landing, boeing-737, aircraft-carrier

I have seen a flight simulator (X-Plane 11) video of landing a 737 on an aircraft carrier (and stopped). Is it possible to land a 737 in real life? What is the biggest aircraft that it is possible to land on an aircraft carrier?

Comment: But I also asked: what is the biggest aircraft that can land on an aircraft carrier

Comment: Pretty sure there were some demo tests landing a C-130 on a carrier.

Comment: I was asking about the 737 not the C-130...

Comment: @LeonardTan Then consider creating that as a separate question

Comment: The 737 is addressed in the linked question.

Comment: The guys on deck in the video look so nonchalant as the wing sweeps right over their heads...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **unloaded** 737, flown by a top-tier pilot can stop incredibly fast, generally in a shorter distance than a Cessna-172 flown by a student (typically around 900 ft:  I've seen planes at Boeing Field, land 32L and stop well before A9).

Because the brakes are meant to stop a fully loaded plane on a wet runway, they are extremely powerful when the plane is empty and the braking action is good.

Although it has never been attempted (to the best of my knowledge), I think a 737, near empty weight, in optimal conditions, could likely land on a carrier with a 1,000 ft deck steaming into the wind (lets estimate headwind + carrier speed for a combined effective wind of 50kts).

Another consideration, however, would be if there's enough space for the 737's massive wing span.

Comment: A quick Google search indicates a 737 has a wingspan about half as wide as the flight deck of a Nimitz-class carrier.

Comment: Is it possible to land it without headwind tho?

Comment: Now what? There's a 737 on the flight deck. Who'd like to do a take-off?